# Awk variable print wrong shell script

Tags: shell, awk, printing

Though i is set 1 why it is printing whole file instead of specific condition?

Please show my example

```
oracle@localhost% i=1
oracle@localhost% cat listener.tmp | awk   '{print $1 } '
LISTENER_BIL
oracle@localhost% cat listener.tmp | awk   '{print $2 } '
LISTENER_AP
oracle@localhost% cat listener.tmp | awk   '{print $i } '
LISTENER_BIL LISTENER_AP
oracle@localhost% echo $i
1
```

Thanks
Uzzal

Comment: This is not the way BASH variables work in `awk`, you should try `i=1;awk  -v val="$i" '{print $val }'  listener.tmp` once. Also you need not to use `cat` with `awk` programs it can read file itself, so I removed it too.

Comment: @UzzalBasak : In your code, you set the variable `i`, but you don't use it anywhere. Also, you are talking about some "specific condition", but I don't see any condition in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's working Successfully

```
for (( i = 1; i < $COUNT_LISTENER+1 ; i++));
```

do 
        LISTENER_XXXX=`${CAT} ${TEMPFILE} | ${AWK} -v val="$i" '{print $val}'`
        ${ECHO} $LISTENER_XXXX >> ${LOGDIR}/listener_EXEC.log
done